# vim syntax file: composite keywords

Tags: syntax-highlighting

What if I define keywords as combination of two list of strings?

E.g.

List1:

```
['B', 'G96', 'TPSS', 'RevTPSS', 'BRx', PBE', 'PBEh', 'wPBEh']
```

List2:

```
['VWN', 'P86', 'PW91', 'TPSS']
```

and a keyword is a combination of a word in List1 + a word in List2, e.g. 'RevTPSSTPSS' is a keyword, but a single 'TPSS' is not. How do I write the Gaussian syntax file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
let list1 = ['B', 'G96', 'TPSS', 'RevTPSS', 'BRx', 'PBE', 'PBEh', 'wPBEh']
let list2 = ['VWN', 'P86', 'PW91', 'TPSS']
for a in list1
  for b in list2
    execute 'syntax keyword MyGroup' a . b
  endfor
endfor

highlight link MyGroup Function
```

The most relevant help sections are `:h :execute` and `:h syn-keyword`, so you might want to read those.